# How I can handle integer overflow?

Tags: c, int, overflow

I am trying to handle integer overflow. My code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<limits.h>

int isInt (char *s)
{
 char *ep = NULL;
 long i = strtol (s, &ep, 10);
 if ((*ep == 0) || (!strcmp(ep,"\n")))
    return 1;  // it's an int

 return 0;  
} 

int main()
{
char *buffer = NULL;
size_t count = 0;
ssize_t ret;
//AMINO *a_acid;
int num;

for(;;)
{   
printf("Please enter an integer:");
if((ret = getline(&buffer, &count, stdin)) < 0)
{
    perror("getline: error\n");
    free(buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

if(!isInt(buffer))
{
    perror("you are not entering int , Try again:");
    continue;
}
sscanf(buffer, "%d",&num);
printf("%d\n", num);
if ((num > INT_MAX)|| (num < 0))
{
    perror("you overflowed int variable , Try again:\n ");
    continue;
}
break;
}

}
```

Now I was checking how this code is responding. And I saw something weird.When I am entering so big number, then it is detected. But sometimes is not getting detected.
Here is my terminal view:

```
> nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:~/2nd_sem/biophysics$ gcc torson.c 
> nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:~/2nd_sem/biophysics$ ./a.out
> Please enter an integer:ksdjfjklh 
> you are not entering int , Try again:: Success
> Please enter an integer:338479759475637465765
> -1 
> you overflowed int variable , Try again:  : Numerical result out of  
> range 
> Please enter an integer:58678946895785 
> 1103697833
> nazmul@nazmul-Lenovo-G50-80:~/2nd_sem/biophysics$
```

*Why it is working for this number 338479759475637465765. But it is not working for 58678946895785. logic , I used in my program, is when it is out of bound, then int variable gives some -1 or negative value. I read many article, still it is not quite clear.

Comment: ignore that line. I edited some code from isfloat() to isInt()

Comment: The second and third use of `perror()` does not make sense. I

Comment: Also please take a bit of time and indent the code properly.

Comment: And an [mcve] would be better

Comment: `num > INT_MAX` is never true. Since `num` is an `int`, its value is never bigger than `INT_MAX`. What likely happened is that, when you entered a large number, overflow occurred inside `scanf` (which likely has behavior not defined by the C standard; I have not checked this specific point), and the result was that a negative value was placed in `int`. Then this triggered your test `num < 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtol` converts the value to a `long int`, whose range might be distinct from `int`. Furthermore, it returns `LONG_MAX` or `LONG_MIN` if the value could be converted but is *outside* the range for `long int`. In that case, `errno` will be set to `ERANGE` (but not otherwise!) Also, in the case of matching failure the value returned is 0, but `errno` is not set; but the `ep` points to the beginning of the string.

```
int isInt (char *s)
{
   char *ep = NULL;

   // zero errno first!
   errno = 0;
   long i = strtol (s, &ep, 10);
   if (errno) {
       return 0;
   }

   // matching failure.
   if (ep == s) {
       return 0;
   }

   // garbage follows
   if (! ((*ep == 0) || (!strcmp(ep,"\n")))) {
      return 0;
   }

   // it is outside the range of `int`
   if (i < INT_MIN || i > INT_MAX) {
      return 0;
   }

   return 1; 
}
```

---

What dbush says about the use of `perror` is correct, though. `strtol` sets an error only in case of `long` overflow, which is not the only possible failing case in your function, so `perror` could print anything like `Is a directory` or `Multihop attempted`.

Comment: very helpful.But If I check over flow for long long int, I can not do this way, right? what you are doing is you are converting input as long in for checking overflow for int then compare it with INT_MIN or INT_MAX .like wise for checking overflow in long in, I can use strtoll and the compare it with LLONG_MIN or LLONG_MAX.But, how do i check overflow for long long int?

Answer (score 2):

`sscanf(buffer, any_format_without_width, &anytype);` is **not** sufficient to detect overflow.

> if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined. C11dr §7.21.6.2 10

Do not use `*scanf()` family to detect overflow.  It may work in select cases, but not in general.

---

Instead use `strto**()` functions.  Yet even OP's `isInt()` is mis-coded as it incorrectly assess  `isInt("\n")`, `isInt("")`, `isInt("999..various large values ...999")` as good `int`s.

Alternative:

```
bool isint_alt(const char *s) {
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  long y = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);

  if (s == endptr) {
    return false; // No conversion
  }

  if (errno == ERANGE) {
    return false; // Outside long range
  }

  if (y < INT_MIN || y > INT_MAX) {
    return false; // Outside int range
  }

  // Ignore trailing white space
  while (isspace((unsigned char)*endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }

  if (*endptr) {
    return false; // Trailing junk
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: If only the `*scanf` functions would say something like "the value is the same as the return value of `strtoimax`, converted to the appropriate type". :/

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes, the "the behavior is undefined." is the killer for typical use of `*scanf()`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting your types mixed up.

In the `isInt` function you use `strtol`, which return a `long` to check the value.  Then in your `main` function you use `sscanf` with `%d`, which reads into an `int`.

On your system, it seems that a `long` is 64 bits while an `int` is 32 bits.  So `strtol` fails to fully convert 338479759475637465765 because it is larger than a 64 bit variable can hold.  Then you try to convert 58678946895785 which **will** fit in a 64 bit variable but **not** a 32 bit variable.

You should instead have `sscanf` read into a `long`.  Then you can compare the value against `INT_MAX`:

```
long num;
...
sscanf(buffer, "%ld", &num);
printf("%ld\n", num);
if ((num > INT_MAX)|| (num < INT_MIN))
{
    printf("you overflowed int variable , Try again:\n ");
    continue;
}
```

Also note that it doesn't make sense to call `perror` here.  You only use it right after calling a function which sets `errno`.

Comment: I understand. But still I have one query. After taking input in long int , I have to compare with INT_MAX to check overfow in respect of int .Then when I would take long int input, then I have check against long long int. If i take input in long long int , then how I check overflow.  I mean, Here I wanted int input, so I take it in long int variable and check it with INT_MAX. But, when I want to take long long int, then how can I check overflow?

Comment: I disagree. `sscanf` is not a sound advice, because with `sscanf` you *cannot tell* if the value overflowed or not. It works only *iff* range of `long int` is distinct from `int`. Furthermore OPs code contained a check for newline or 0 i.e. that the line was terminated just after the number- yours will discard trailing characters.

Comment: The proper course of action is to use the `strtol` code, check `ERANGE`, then compare against `INT_{MAX|MIN}`

Answer (score 1):

If one *must* use `sscanf()` to detect `int` overflow rather than the robust `strtol()`, there is a cumbersome way.

Use a wider type and a width limit to prevent overflow when scanning.

```
bool isint_via_sscanf(const char *s) {
  long long y;
  int n = 0;
  if (sscanf(s, "18%lld %n", &y, &n) != 1) {  // Overflow not possible
    return false;  // Conversion failed 
  }

  if (y < INT_MIN || y > INT_MAX) {
    return false; // Outside int range
  }

  if (s[n]) {
    return false;  // Trailing junk
  }

  return true;  
}
```

It is insufficient on rare platforms where `INT_MAX > 1e18`.

It also incorrectly returns input like `"lots of leading space and/or lot of leading zeros 000123"` as invalid.

More complex code using `sscanf()` can address these short-comings, yet the best approach is `strto*()`.